# Managing Resources (file object) in a Factory Pattern

Tags: python, parsing, io, contextmanager

*Sideote*: I'm not sure if the title is perfect, because I am not sure about the right keywords to use here.

I have a function that is supposed to read and/or write files in different formats and load data from them. The parser logic depends on the file format, and to deduce the correct format I need to read the file's header. Currently, I am using a Factory (think plugin manager) that opens the file and checks which plugin can parse the file.

My problem is managing the file resource while instantiating the correct parser. Here is a an example of what I am currently doing (with made-up files):

```py
import io

class OpenWrapper:
    # shimmed in between for visualization purposes
    def __init__(self, filename:io.BytesIO, mode) -> None:
        self.file = filename
        self.mode = mode
        self.instance = None

    def __enter__(self):
        print("Opening File")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("Closing File")

class FormatA:
    def __init__(self, filename, file_handle:OpenWrapper):
        # check if format can read file
        file_handle.file.seek(0)
        expected_header = "FormatA".encode()
        header = file_handle.file.read(len(expected_header))
        if header != expected_header:
            raise RuntimeError("Can not parse this file.")

        self.filename = filename
        self.file_handler:OpenWrapper = None

    def read(self):
        if self.file_handler is not None:
            # skip header
            self.file_handler.file.seek(8)
            data = self.file_handler.file.read().decode("utf-8")
        else:
            with OpenWrapper(self.filename, "rb") as file_handle:
                file_handle.file.seek(8)
                data = file_handle.file.read().decode("utf-8")

        return data.split("_")

    def __enter__(self):
        self.file_handler = OpenWrapper(self.filename, "rb").__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.file_handler is not None:
            self.file_handler.__exit__(type, value, traceback)

class ParserFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.known_plugins = [FormatA]

    def __call__(self, filename):
        mode = "rb" # hardcoded for demonstration purposes

        with OpenWrapper(filename, mode) as file_handle:
            for plugin_class in self.known_plugins:
                try:
                    plugin = plugin_class(filename, file_handle)
                finally:
                    break
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Could not find parser.")

        return plugin

fancy_loader = ParserFactory()

file1 = io.BytesIO("FormatA\nDATA_DATA_DATA_DATA".encode())
file2 = io.BytesIO("UNIQUE_FORMAT_B_HEADERDATA_DATA_DATA".encode())

# scenario 1
print("Scenario 1")
print("==========")
with fancy_loader(file1) as data_file:
    print(data_file.read())

# scenario 2
print("\n")
print("Scenario 2")
print("==========")
data_file = fancy_loader(file1)
print(data_file.read())
```

If you run the example above, it will print the following:

```
Scenario 1
==========
Opening File
Closing File
Opening File
['DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA']
Closing File


Scenario 2
==========
Opening File
Closing File
Opening File
Closing File
['DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA']
```

This works, but is somewhat inefficient, because `Scenario 1` opens and closes the file twice, whereas it really only needs to do so once. I.e., my ideal flow here would be

```
Scenario 1
==========
Opening File
['DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA']
Closing File


Scenario 2
==========
Opening File
Closing File
Opening File
Closing File
['DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA', 'DATA']
```

Is it possible to somehow pass the ownership of the file from `ParserFactory` to `FormatA` without closing it in `Scenario 1`, while - at the same time - closing the file in `Scenario2`?

Comment: Your question boils down to how to optimize the opening and closing of the file. Frankly I think it's a classic case of premature optimization.

Comment: @martineau I'm not sure I understand your comment. I agree that it is about optimizing the opening and closing of a file, but I don't get where I fall into premature optimization. Could you elaborate?

Comment: [Premature Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) and [When to optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: @martineau Sure. Here is one of my use-cases: `dataset = [fancy_loader(filename).read() for filename in Path(...).iterdir()]` where `Path(...)` points to a location on a network drive (access is slow) with a lot of files. I could - of course - change the parser to read from a file object instead and wrap the actual files in caching logic, but that seems less maintainable (and less desirable) than simply using a context manager and reading the file once instead of twice.